# Hi-Low lines in Plotly Line Chart

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to replicate this excel line chart in python using plotly.

[image: Excel Line Chart]

Is there any way to add the high-low lines between the two line graphs in Plotly?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? With `matplotlib` you can use `fill_between` and set the `hatch='|'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trace_1 = go.Scatter(x=x_arr, y=y1_arr, name='plot1', line=dict(color = ('royalblue')), mode='lines+markers')

    trace_2 = go.Scatter(x=x_arr, y=y2_arr, name='plot2', line=dict(color = ('orange')), mode='lines+markers')

    layout_1 = go.Layout(
        height=420,
        width=800,

        title=go.layout.Title(
            text='title',
        ),
        xaxis=go.layout.XAxis(
            title='x axis',
        ),
        yaxis=go.layout.YAxis(
            title='y axis',
        )
    )

    data = []
    trace_3_arr = np.array([])

    for i in range(0, len(x_arr)):
        trace_i = go.Scatter(x=[x_arr[i], x_arr[i]], y=[y1_arr[i], y2_arr[i]], line=dict(color = ('black'), width=1), showlegend=False)
        trace_3_arr = np.append(trace_3_arr, trace_i)
        data.append(trace_i)

    data.append(trace_1)
    data.append(trace_2)

    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout_1)

    plot(fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on this post. Plotly doesn't seem to have a property to draw lines between points of 2 line plots. So I made the connecting lines as an array of trace and then plotted them on the same figure. Here's a snapshot of resulting plot

[image: my plot]:

Comment: @vestland sure I will post them below